# Selenium Headless with Service

Tags: selenium

I know you can run Selenium headless alongside WebDriver, but is there a way to do so with the service? I'm trying the following and it just opens the browser normally, seemingly ignoring Xvfb. This is on a Mac if that happens to matter.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver;
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service

# ...

self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
self.display.start()

self.service = service.Service('/path/to/chromedriver');
self.service.start();

# Various Chrome option stuff clipped

browser = webdriver.Remote(self.service.service_url, desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities());
```

Fyi -- not a real solution, but for the time being, I'm using Chrome's window-size and window-position flags to keep selenium out of the way e.g.,

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
options.add_argument('--window-size=100,100')
options.add_argument('--window-position=100,1200')
browser = webdriver.Remote(service_url, desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this is what you want: [generalredneck/headless-selenium](https://github.com/generalredneck/headless-selenium)